# Displaying Data in play framework using Ebean and twirl

Tags: javascript, jquery, playframework, ebean, twirl

I am trying to display my data (in a table) which is in Html format.

```
package models;

import com.avaje.ebean.Ebean;
import com.avaje.ebean.text.json.JsonContext;
import play.db.ebean.Model;
import play.twirl.api.Html;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class BarChartData extends Model {
public String username;
public int number;


public static Model.Finder<String,BarChartData> find = new Model.Finder<String,BarChartData>(
    String.class, BarChartData.class
);

public static List<BarChartData> getBarChartData(){
    List<BarChartData> Data = new ArrayList<BarChartData>();
    Data = Ebean.find(BarChartData.class).findList();
    return Data;
}

//passing data from Sql in Json format
public static String JsonStyleData(){
    JsonContext json = Ebean.json();
    String jsonOutput = json.toJson(getBarChartData());
    return jsonOutput;
}

//passing json format data in Html
public static Html chartData(){
    Html chartData = new Html(JsonStyleData());
    return chartData;
}
```

In index.scala.html I have this variable which contains my data. I am wondering how can I use this variable to display/Edit my data.

```
@(D3DataNPost: Html)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Display:**

`D3DataNPost` is just stringified JSON, so you can print it by calling `@D3DataNPost` in the template.

```
@(D3DataNPost: Html) 

<script>
  var D3DataNPost = @D3DataNPost;

  console.log(D3DataNPost); 
</script>
```

**Edit:**

Well, better to edit it before you stringify it, like some method right after calling `getBarChartData()`. Or ... Just do it in Javascript on the client side.